# Limpiar funcion al desmontar el componente en el useEffect de React

Tags: reactjs

tengo un proyecto en React Hecho con React hooks, en el que al cargar el componente hero de un pagina llama a una función que tiene una animación con js.

Esta función tiene un set interval. Cuando hago click a otra página antes de que acabe el interval (se sigue ejecturando) y falla la página porque claro no es la pagina home y no encuentra varios elementos id.

Como puedo desuscribirme o limpiar la funcion al desmontar el componente con react hooks?

os dejo el use effect que tengo ahora pero que no funciona, no lo limpia.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    Animations.hero()
    return () => Animations.hero(); 

  }, [component,])
```

Comment: Te suscribes con: `Animations.hero()`, y tambien te desuscribes con: `Animations.hero()`, la logica seria que para desuscribirte tengas una funcion diferente a `hero()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal cual comenta **Shassain** debes tener un método que te permita suscribirte y otro que te permita desuscribirse para que todo el ciclo funcione de forma correcta tal cual lo explican en la documentación oficial de **ReactJS**

**Enlace oficial:** https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html

Algo así como esto:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

class Animation {
  constructor() {
    this.count = 0;
    this.animation = null;
  }
  start() {
    this.animation = setInterval(() => {
      this.count++;
      console.log("animation hero", this.count);
    }, 1000);
  }
  stop() {
    clearInterval(this.animation);
  }
}

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const animation = new Animation();
    animation.start();
    return () => animation.stop();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello Hero</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```